Is it possible to get the app instance string directly from a wix backend function?
The below documentation explains how to get the app instance string from the frontend, but wondering if it is possible to get it from a wix backend function as well? The backend function is defined in my app and will call one of my other APIs. I am hoping to authenticate the request to my other API using the app instance string as well.
https://dev.wix.com/docs/build-apps/develop-your-app/frameworks/wix-cli/app-development/authenticate-incoming-requests-to-your-backend#step-2--send-the-app-instance

You can use the getAppInstance() function. Note that this function requires elevated permissions, so you're going to have to send the authorization from somewhere. This is usually done by calling fetchWithAuth() from the frontend.
